# Why can't I execute a Cygwin .exe directly with Java on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, cygwin, processbuilder

I've installed Cygwin but can't seem to access any commands directly. For example, the process below doesn't start due to bash.exe not found even though I'm specifying it's absolute path. I know it's installed correctly since I can see this path in the File Explorer. However, searching for any cygwin file doesn't return any hits which is odd.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe", "-c", "ls");
Process p = pb.start();

java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "‪C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\tyea1\Documents\Log Bundles\latest_PRODXIO01"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

If I add cygwin's bin to the Windows PATH variable, I can successfully execute "ls" via

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "ls");
Process p = pb.start();
```

I still can't access bash.exe directly when it's in the PATH.

I don't understand what is going on here and why I can't execute bash.exe directly.

Comment: I can not repro this error.  I also have Cygwin installed in c:\cygwin64, and I just tried writing a simple Java program using your code.  It does not repro at all.

Comment: I'm running a Windows 10 ISO image in Mac Bootcamp. The Windows OS isn't activated with a product key but it works. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Can you start cygwin using `c:\cygwin64\Cygwin.bat`? And run `ls` or `ls -a`. If not, make that work! If or when that works, try again, or try using `ProcessBuilder("C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe", "--login", "-c", "ls")`.

Comment: I can't use cygwin.bat either. It complains about bash. I don't know what is going on.

bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell

Comment: I'm getting closer. This is my ProcessBuilder string:

[cmd, /c, ‪C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe, -c, ls]

Reading the output in Java gives me "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect." but if I execute "C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe -c ls" directly in cmd, the output is what I expect.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't exactly answered my own question but found something that works. With the cygwin \bin in the Windows PATH, my process builder string is:

[cmd, /c, C:\cygwin64\bin\sh.exe, -c, ls]

This seems to be working. I'm using sh.exe instead of bash.exe so that I can use all of cygwin's bin files.