# Why are some Cygwin files not executable?

Tags: java, windows, cygwin

I'm attempting to execute Cygwin commands on Windows from a Java application. In cygwin's bin, I noticed some files are Application type (.exe) while others (like zcat and zless) have no extension and are just File type.

I've added the bin to the Windows PATH and seem to only be able to execute the .exe files from cmd. The code below works.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "ls");
Process p = pb.start();
```

I want to use things like zcat and zless but they aren't executable and cmd complains that 'zcat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

If I manually change the file to .exe, I get a pop-up error saying zcat can't start or run due to incompatibility with 64-bit versions of Windows. I've installed the 64-bit version of cygwin (setup-x86_64). Why isn't all of cygwin's bin executable?

Comment: Add "." to the `PATHEXT` environment variable to allow CMD to execute a PE image that has no file extension. It won't help of course if the internal `CreateProcessW` call fails because the file isn't a valid 32- or 64-bit PE image. It will fall back on `ShellExecuteExW`, which looks up the registered "." file association.

Comment: `zcat` is probably an sh or bash shell script, so they must be run with `sh` or `bash`, not with `cmd`, which is for Windows scripts only.

Comment: After adding "." to PATHNEXT, cmd can find the command but it can't execute it for being incompatible with 64-bit Windows. I have the 64-bit cygwin installed so I guess there is nothing else I can do.

Comment: Try `type "path\to\zcat"` to check whether it's a Unix shell script, i.e. a text file containing a shebang line and Unix shell commands. If so, you can run it via `sh -c "path/to/zcat"`. In Windows, it's possible to associate "." (i.e. files with no extension) with a progid template command like `"path\to\sh.exe" -c "%1" %*` -- but I wouldn't recommend it, and it may not work anyway since Windows will substitute a DOS path for the "%1" target path, which sh.exe may not support.

Comment: That's another problem I have. I cannot execute any cygwin commands directly for some reason. I can only use them when they are in the PATH from cmd.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54818613/why-cant-i-execute-a-cygwin-exe-directly-with-java-on-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the cygwin programs are NOT binary program but script one.
The command `file` can give you a description of the file type:

```
$ file zcat
zcat: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

while

```
$ file cat
cat: PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

reading the first 5 rows of zcat

```
$ head -n 5 zcat
#!/bin/sh
# Uncompress files to standard output.

# Copyright (C) 2007, 2010-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

we see on first row the `#!` that says that is a script to be executed by the 
`/bin/sh` interpreter.

In other case we can have

```
$ head -n5 2to3
#!/usr/bin/python2.7.exe
import sys
from lib2to3.main import main

sys.exit(main("lib2to3.fixes"))
```

so `2to3` is a python 2.7 script

Comment: I see. So I can use cmd to run the executables, but will have to invoke the shell interpreter for the others. Can I use cmd to invoke sh or will I have to invoke /bin/sh directly?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is only understood within cygwin. Uses `path\to\sh.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Nobody else has said this, so for anybody else looking for this ... if you need to run the "z..." commands from the `cmd` window AND you have the `cygwin` bin directory in your path, you can run them (yea, it's a bit klugy) using bash, as in

`bash zcat file.gz`

etc.

Or you can run them directly from the `cygwin` terminal.

FWIW I had to find the 'more' utilities and load them.  For some reason they weren't in my initial set of packages I downloaded